SQL - grouping instances together
In SQL I am trying to group these values into single events, so that table 1 results in table 2.
Table 1



id
Value




1
0


2
1


3
2


4
3


5
0


6
1


7
2


8
3


9
4


10
5


11
0


12
1


13
2


14
3


15
4


16
5


17
6


18
0



Table 2



max(id),min(id)
Max(Value),Min(Value)




(4,2)
(3,1)


(10,6)
(5,1)


(17,12)
(6,1)



Unsure how to do this, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question

This is a gaps and islands problem.  One approach uses the LAG() function to generate a column which identifies the islands.  Then, we can aggregate by island to find the min/max values.
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT t.*, CASE WHEN LAG(Value) OVER (ORDER BY id) = 0 AND Value != 0
                     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS grp
    FROM yourTable t
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT t.*, SUM(grp) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS seq
    FROM cte1 t
)

SELECT
    MAX(id) AS id_max,
    MIN(id) AS id_min,
    MAX(Value) AS value_max,
    MIN(Value) AS value_min
FROM cte2
WHERE Value != 0
GROUP BY seq
ORDER BY seq;


Here is a working demo of the above query using your sample data.
